# My recent jobs have me doing work other than my skills and different to the job description

Tags: professionalism, software-industry

I'm a front end developer, I specialise in user interface web development using a technology stack mainly mostly of HTML, CSS, JS along with common flavours such as TypeScript, React, Angular, Sass, etc.

Over the last couple years and jobs I've found myself performing the majority of daily tasks doing things other than what I specialise in. Previously I've left jobs or contracts due to this but after a couple of years of the same pattern repeating I'm wondering if this is normal or my self branding is giving off the wrong signal (i.e. I say I do X but always volunteer for Y so people think I can do X, Y, and Z).

As some examples, I've only ever branded myself as a front end web developer and have only applied for positions with those job titles, and this is what jobs end up like:

- I have been placed on a project to develop AR/VR applications without having any prior experience with WebXR or 3D skills
- I am frequently asked to develop web backend software
- Tasked with reviewing database schemas and auditing performance of queries
- Administering Active Directory (creating user accounts, migrating on-premise to cloud products)
- Providing solutions assessments and market research of options (tasks usually given to Business Analysts or Solution Architects in my experience)
- System administration activities (schedule backups, SSL generation, etc)
- Defining team strategies for future growth (I have no management duties defined as part of my role)

I get that any job isn't 100% just what you want to do but I'm finding over the last few years I've actually done less front end work than any other task. So much so that I feel I'm out of touch with the landscape and don't feel confident in my front end skills enough to keep that title or apply for new jobs. Over the last 12 months I have probably only performed front end web dev duties for about 1-2 months. In fact, I've updated my email signature to drop "Front End" and now only say "Web Developer".

The most recent example of this issue for me is that I applied for a job as a front end developer and started that position 6 months ago. I specifically left my old job due the high degree of context switching, and because the new position was using tech I wanted to learn so that I gain deep expertise and call myself and expert (hopefully). In the months I've been in this new role not only has the tech I desired to work with been eliminated from the company but I haven't done any real front end work. Most of my days are administering AWS, fixing email accounts, and troubleshooting backend API code.

Another point of annoyance is when a colleague/manager comments on a task saying "it's front end work, you can get this done fast since you're the expert". It quite a hard thing to hear because that's how I brand myself but since I've been put on non-related tasks for so long, even simple front end tasks are becoming a challenge for me as I'm finding that I'm just simply out of practice.

This pattern has been my experience of the web developer industry for the last few years.

I'm in need of some perspective before I approach my manager asking for narrower duties so that I can do what I want to specialise in (my personal brand) or before I decide it's time to find another job. For reference, I usually stick around at a job for 3+ years, so far this one is 6 months, and my previous job started to dilute the consistency at which I was working on front end dev tasks.

I like working with React and Angular from a user interface perspective. I'm not really interested in being a database admin or other areas.

So, am I overreacting here and wanting to be treated like a unique snowflake that only gets to play with their favourite toys, or is performing broad duties like this normal and I need to make my peace with the situation?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere could you elaborate or link to a resource which might help with asking the right questions? I felt I was quite clear in this interview process as I've learned the hard way before, so this time my questions and statements were along the lines of "I only do front end as that's where I want to grow and have skills, I don't enjoy backend nor do I have skills or desire to grow in that direction". I feel that the Active Directory policies and desktop support role is quite outside of my domain however.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere my previous company was a consulting/contracting company doing exactly what you said. It didn't work out as expected over time. First couple of years were good then things started to change.

Answer (score 1):

Every job I've had boiled down to "getting the job done", not necessarily doing what I was specifically hired to do.  Needs change over time.

Sometimes that included expanding my horizons to take on what was needed, not what I had experience with.

You seem to be complaining that your employer wants you to take responsibility for things outside your area of expertise.  I'd consider that a good thing and an opportunity to learn and also to note at your review time.

Be professional and a learn to learn new things and it will be much better for your career in the long run.  I've found that being versatile and willing to step out of the box when needed is much more valuable than being a "snowflake".

Comment: I agree partially with this. My issue is being hired as a React dev and I haven't worked with it since April, rather my days are spent on Azure AD policy administration or .NET Framework legacy code. Perhaps it's a compliment my employer wants me doing more but I don't need to expand. There is a possibility the employer sees me as "just as dev" and therefore if it's IT related they think "just get a dev to do it". The risk with being too versatile is not having any specialisation and being a "master of none".

Comment: Further to my previous comment. The fact I get the additional work done is probably an issue too. As long as I deliver they will realise I can be useful. Perhaps at some point I just need to either say no (which will be difficult since it's my manager assigning the work) or I start to under deliver on tasks which are outside of my direct domain of expertise. E.g. pretend that database tuning tasks take me days but React tasks take me hours.

Comment: In that case your best option is likely to find another position and you'll want to be very clear during the interview process that you are a React developer and nothing else.  That could be quite career limiting but that appears to be what you want.

Comment: Funny you say that, because the last job and this one, I made very clear in the interview process I want this role purely to focus on React and become considered an expert (both interviews said they liked that I had a goal and wanted someone to fill that React gap in their business). The fact it's happening over multiple years and jobs makes me feel like this might be normal. Thus I'm seeking external input to validate and verify.

Comment: Then perhaps you should be looking at different types of companies.  It sounds like yours may be smaller and not have dedicated AD, DB, and other teams.  If you look at larger companies they may have an entire team that just does DB work and another that just does React front-end work.  The smaller the company the more likely you will be called upon to handle things that are outside your immediate area of expertise.  Frankly I feel as though you are in the process of intentionally crippling your career in order to be a "React Developer Expert".

Comment: If that's the case, you are going to need to find the specific company and position that needs React experts so badly that they will never ask them to do anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You might be onto something there. I've come from enterprise organisations (think >120,000 staff) so this new role is in a team of < 30. Thought I'd try the other direction but perhaps I was just unlucky in the large org and now the small one is as you described. I'll think further and consider your words. Much appreciated.